# Export Signed .Apk From Existing Android Project Via Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

**UPDATE - PROJECT VALUES**

**Eclipse/Android Problem**

Does anyone have a straightforward solution to this problem encountered whilst importing an existing Android project into Eclipse.

The intention of using an existing Android project was specifically to utilise the Eclipse ADT Export Wizard to produce a signed .apk that should work on an Android device **version 2.3.3 upward**.

The existent Android project has already been tested on my device (Android version 2.3.3) and functions correctly.

**Tools used:**

Android SDK/Eclipse IDE bundle (March 2014), plus Java JDK (March 2014).

All tools function correctly.

**Import Existing Android Project Process:**

Open Eclipse > File > New > Project > Android Project From Existing Code > Next > Browse to select project from root directory > Select project > Finish).

This process worked & the existing Android project was imported & displayed the left hand side of the Eclipse console under the Project Explorer View.

I then signed the project using the Eclipse ADT Export Wizard before exporting the final .apk.

**Summary:**

All software appeared to work correctly.
Signing process appeared to have worked correctly.
Export of .apk appeared to have worked correctly.

I can import an existing Android project into Eclipse successfully.
I can sign the .apk successfully.
I can export the .apk successfully.

However, the resultant .apk would not install on my mobile device (Android Build 2.3.3).

**RE: AndroidManifest.xml:**

minSDKVersion = "10"
targetSDKVersion ="19"

**RE: project.properties:**

target=android-19

Comment: What, if any, error message is displayed when you try to install the APK?

Comment: Did you uninstall the debug version before trying to install the signed one ?

Comment: Check if you have the same app(with same package name) on your device and its signature is different or it has same signature but its version_code is greater then your new apk.

Comment: No error messages displayed when trying to install the APK. All previous versions were removed from my device before trying a new install.

Comment: Try using `adb install` command. This should give out an error message if the install is not successful.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to look & reply to this question. The procedure outlined above worked after a reinstall of the Eclipse IDE / Android SDK bundle (March 2014).

Answer (score 0):

Just a possibility; have you gone through the device's settings --> apps --> all --> myApp --> remove process? even if it's a debugging keystore you are signing that with, it is probably different, and the phone won't install that.

If that doesn't work, could you post your logcat from the period around when you install the app?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for taking the time to look at & reply to this question. The procedure outlined above worked after a reinstall of the Eclipse IDE / Android SDK bundle (March 2014).